# Mysql-query "order" does not work on providers server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the simple SQL-query:

```
SELECT * FROM roadtrips
ORDER BY start_datum DESC, 
         von_benutzername DESC;
```

(where start_datum is start_date) which works on my local server (Version: ibmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503). With working I mean that the results are ordered for start_date. It also does work in phpmyadmin-enviroment of my provider (Version: phpMyAdmin - 2.11.11.3
MySQL-Client-Version: 5.1.61, my provider is: df.eu (domain factory) ) but it does not work - and that means the results are not ordered for start_date - when I access my website where the sql from above is executed. What could be the reasons for this?

Comment: Doesn't work how? Does it give you any error?

Comment: You need to explain this  *it does not work*. Are you getting any error or the results the were not ordered ?

Comment: What does "*does not work*" mean? what happens when you execute it from website? nothing? do results come back unsorted? wrong results? does machine explode?

Comment: with not working I mean that the results are not ordered - I added this in the starting message.

Comment: If it works fine on PhpMyAdmin, then the problem is probably in your website code.

Comment: how are you using this code? working in phpmyadmin-enviroment means it is working and as far as i know there is no such bug or change for order in any version of MySQL

Comment: Then either website is not sending the order by clause, or the results are being re-ordered after they come back to website by the code that displays them in the html.

Comment: when I invoke the website on my local server the right ordering is displayed so it is also not a reordering in my html code and the order by clause is sended. Here a link to my website code: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-32394355/Bildschirmfoto2016-12-31um17.20.37.png.html

Comment: edit: it gets reordered! Somehow the php function date("d.m.Y",$datum) seems to influence the ordering of my query after it was made ?! How can that be?

Comment: looks like you hit the classic strtotime parse problem. try using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Note: don't omit ` DateTimeZone` parameter.

Comment: Did you try executing the query directly vis-à-vis MySQL (command line or Workbench)? If yes, do you get the result in the correct order? If yes, Did you try logging on screen the result at the client's side? If yes, what do you get?